# Why is my cout statement with "? :" not going into else section after ":"

Tags: c++, xcode, conditional-operator

I encountered a problem with my cout statement that utilizes a conditional ternary operator not printing out
This is the printing line in my main:

```
cout << "Enter name to be removed from the list: " << endl;
cin >> targetName;
cout << targetName << (list.deleteNode(targetName) ? " - deleted!" : " - not found!") << endl;
```

This is my deleteNode function:

```
bool StudentList::deleteNode(string target)
{
    ListNode *pCur = head;     // To traverse the list
    while(pCur != NULL){
        if(pCur->stu.name == target){
            if(pCur == head){   // check the first data
                head = pCur->forw;
                delete pCur;
                return true;
            }
            else if(pCur != head && pCur->forw != NULL){  // check data between head an tail
                ListNode* tmp = pCur->back;
                tmp->forw = pCur->forw;
                pCur->forw->back = tmp;
                delete pCur;
                return true;
            }
            else if(pCur != head && pCur->forw == NULL){  // check last data
                pCur->back->forw = pCur->forw;
                delete pCur;
                return true;
            }
        }
        pCur = pCur->forw;
    }
    return false;
}
```

Example Output:

```
Delete [Y/N]?Y
Enter name to be removed from the list: 
Aaa
Aaa
```

The output should've been "Aaa - not found!" but it only prints out the input and program doesn't exit. I would appreciate any suggestions on fixing this problem. Thanks everyone!

Comment: The problem sounds more like there is a loop in your list and `deleteNode()` never returns. Please also post your `addNode()` code.

Comment: Have you tried to step through your code statement by statement in a debugger, while monitoring variables and their values?

Comment: Also for things like lists, I suggest you start with pen and paper, and draw lists using rectangles for nodes and arrows for links (pointers). Erase and redraw the arrows as you perform the operations. I also recommend that you do this while debugging, every time you step over a statement changing a pointer, do the corresponding action on paper.

Comment: I notice you aren't updating the `back` pointer when you remove the `head`. The node that is now `head` has a dangling `back` pointer (presumably). Maybe it is causing UB related to your problem, and if it isn't it will likely cause problems in the future.

Comment: There is no problem with printing or ternary operator. Problem might be somewhere else

Comment: I fixed my code thank you!